# how to trap the location alert response iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, gps, core-location, cllocationmanager

I am using GPS in iphone and it show conformation message for use location service. and i want to trap what user select "Allow" or "No".
can any one suggest how i do this?

Thank

Comment: please post the code that shows the confirmation message

Comment: I am not showing any alert box.. its default alert for allow or no

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't get a direct callback from this alert. However, if the user does not allow Core Location usage, you'll receive a `-locationManager:didFailWithError:` with a `kCLErrorDenied` error to your `CLLocationManagerDelegate`.

Since iOS 4.2, you can also listen to `-locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:` or check the `authorizationStatus` of `CLLocationManager`. This gives you a detailed status.