# Is it possible to call alert "Allow to use current location" manually?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, ios4, core-location

Is it possible to call alert "Allow to use current location" manually when using CoreLocation framework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's automatically displayed when the app accesses Core Location. If the user rejects it, it's displayed a second time at the next launch, then it keeps quiet and isn't shown anymore.

See this answer [how to detect if the user rejected the request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3668214/how-to-trap-the-location-alert-response-iphone/5565627#5565627).